# Content Provider for call log and sms not working

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

In my application I need to get info of every single call(incoming/outgoing/miscall) as well as of messages.For that have used content observer and registered observers at the time of installation of application . But don't know why after registration observer runs and  provide me data once only and then observers do not runs, may be it gets unregistered . My question is that how to register observer permanently as far as my app is installed also the reason why observer is getting unregistered??

Here is my code  for registration

```
public static void registerObserver(Context ctx)
    {   

        resolver = ctx.getContentResolver();
        handler=new SMSHandler();
        call_observer=new CallObserver(handler, ctx);
        resolver.registerContentObserver(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,true,call_observer);

    }
```

Here is call log observer:

```
 public class CallObserver extends ContentObserver {
        private Context context;
        String contact_id = "", email = "", address = "", name = "";
        public static Date date;
        public static SimpleDateFormat sdf;
        public CallObserver(Handler handler, Context context) {
            super(handler);
            this.context = context;
        }
    @Override
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Thread thread = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    Do_Some_Thing();
                }
            };
            thread.start();
            super.onChange(selfChange);
        }
        private void Do_Some_Thing() {
                  Log.e("observer running","observer running");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can use sharedPrefrence to keep it registered.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh thank you sir but how  can you please explain it

Comment: I dont have much knowledge in this case. but check thi link surely helps you. http://vmtuong.wordpress.com/2011/09/08/android-content-observer-for-call-and-sms-logger/